# How to generate file name on current datetime while download in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I am trying to generate the file name using current date time using below code:

```
getFileName() {
    let d = new Date();
    let dformat = [this.padLeft(d.getMonth() + 1),
    this.padLeft(d.getDate()),
    d.getFullYear()].join('') +
      '_' +
      [this.padLeft(d.getHours()),
      this.padLeft(d.getMinutes()),
      this.padLeft(d.getSeconds())].join('');

    console.log("getCurrentDate : ", dformat);
    return "GridWidget_" + dformat + ".csv";
  }

    render() {
return(
    <CSVLink data={data} filename={this.getFileName()} className="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Export To CSV</CSVLink>);
    }
```

Issue with the above code is like File name is not generated with date time while downloading the file, but the time is taken while the page loads. What I want to do is the filename should generated only when the user clicks the download button.

I know this doesn't make much difference in time but requirement is like should generate it with actual date time. Not able to understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can you modify `CSVLink` component? or is it from some library?

Comment: It is component provided to download the file from library "react-csv"

Comment: This is happening because `filename` prop is generated while `render` process, not when a user clicks a link to download.

Comment: I tried this by passing reference, but the filename does not get the function reference, it throws exception "Failed prop type: Invalid prop filename of type function supplied to CSVLink, expected string"

Comment: There is no way to do that unless you re-render `CSVLink` component every second,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default you can't do it because `filename` props is `download` attribute of `<a />` tag which is a built-in HTML. and it generate on render.

`<a download="10-36-45.csv" target="_blank" href="">Export To CSV</a>`

But there is a hack way you can do by using [React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to modify attribute of `<a>` tag.

```
export default class extends Component {
  $CSVLink = React.createRef();

  getFileName() {
    let d = new Date();
    let dformat = `${d.getHours()}-${d.getMinutes()}-${d.getSeconds()}`;

    console.log("getCurrentDate : ", dformat);
    return "GridWidget_" + dformat + ".csv";
  }

  render() {
    const data = [
      { firstname: "Ahmed", lastname: "Tomi", email: "ah@smthing.co.com" },
      { firstname: "Raed", lastname: "Labes", email: "rl@smthing.co.com" },
      { firstname: "Yezzi", lastname: "Min l3b", email: "ymin@cocococo.com" }
    ];
    return (
      <CSVLink
        onClick={() => {
          this.$CSVLink.current.link.download = this.getFileName();
        }}
        ref={this.$CSVLink}
        data={data}
        filename={this.getFileName()}
        className="btn btn-primary"
        target="_blank"
      >
        Export To CSV
      </CSVLink>
    );
  }
}
```

*I change `getFileName` method since I don't have information about `this.padLeft`*, `getFileName` method will return current date so you can see the second changes.

Answer (score 2):

Your getFileName is being called during rendering, you need to call it when the click happens (i.e. CSVLink's onCLick) method. Luckily they provide a way to write async onClick.

First, set a state named `filename`:

```
state = {
  filename: ""
}
```

Now add a callback to CSVLink with asyncOnClick={true}. This function is supposed to be called before any handling logic. [See the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv#--onclick-props).

In that onClick, set your state and once that is finished call `done()`:

```
<CSVLink
  data={data}
  asyncOnClick={true}
  filename={this.state.filename}
  onClick={(event, done) => {
    this.setState({
      filename: this.getFileName()
    }, () => {
      done()
    })
  }}
>
  Download me
</CSVLink>;
```

Comment: I cannot change/use the state, as state change takes much time.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pass the newly generated filename from onClick to CSVLink's props without going through state.

Comment: If you update state in render it will be infinite loop update - render, so cannot update state anyway

Comment: I am not "updating the state in render". `onClick` is a callback which will only be called when the link is clicked, not in every render cycle.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used `filename={this.getFileName()}` which gets called as soon as the component renders.

Since you need the filename to be generated on an event that is being handled inside the CSVLink component you will have to define this function inside the CSVLink component.

Another alternative would be to make the filename prop take a function instead like `filename={this.getFileName}` and inside the CSVLink's `onClick` handler where it uses the `this.props.filename` property you can change it to `this.props.filename()`.

**PS:** `react-csv` allows a `onClick` prop which can be async so you can keep filename as a state variable and then call `setState` in the `onClickHandler` before calling `done()`. The documentation is detailed here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv#--onclick-props

Comment: I tried this but the filename does not get the function reference, it throws exception Failed prop type: Invalid prop `filename` of type `function` supplied to `CSVLink`, expected `string`.

Comment: Is CSVLink from your own codebase or imported from a library? None of these solutions will work if you do not have access to the CSVLink Component since they require you to make changes to the CSVLink component

Comment: used from "react-csv" library

Comment: I see...I think there should be a way around this...I'll update the answer